# Diffie-Hellman: choosing wrong generator "g" parameter and its implications of practical attacks

Tags: diffie-hellman

In traditional DH one chooses two shared parameters: a large prime $p$ and base $g$, which is primitive root $\bmod p$. Suppose that the generation algorithm is broken and $g$ generates only a subgroup (the group with fewer elements than the number of coprimes to $p$), what could be the possible attack? what's the complexity ? are there any real-world examples of attacking wrong DH parameters (implementation)?

Comment: if $g$ generates only a subgroup, then it can be attacked by using small subgroup, only given that the protocol doesn't verify the validation of elements.  you can refer to this [link](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9517/can-you-help-me-clear-a-confusion-about-small-subgroup-attack-on-hmqv). In this page, i give a example of small subgroup attack.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as we know, Diffie-Hellman is secure as long as the subgroup generated by *g* is impervious to [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). When working modulo a prime *p*, this is achieved when the following are met:

- *p* is large enough (at least 1024 bits, go to 2048 bits for a bigger safety margin) and is not a "special form" prime (a randomly generated prime will be fine with overwhelming probability).
- the subgroup generated by *g* has an order *t* which is such that there is at least one prime factor *q* of *t* which is "big enough", i.e. more than *2k* bits, when *k* is the "security level" (e.g. to have at least 80-bit security, *q* should be at least 160 bits).

Note that it is in no way necessary that *g* generates all non-zero integers modulo *p*. It is fine if it generates a strict subgroup, as long as that subgroup cannot be split into several subgroups, each being very small. This is the essence of the necessity of at least one medium-sized prime *q* in the factorization of the subgroup order *t*.

The order of *g*, called *t* above, is a divisor of *p-1*. With overwhelming probability, a randomly generated *g* will imply an order which will not be much smaller than *p*. Indeed, there is only one chance in a billion to hit a *g* which implies an order *t* smaller than *p* by more than 30 bits (because *2<sup>30</sup>* is about one billion). It is preposterous to imagine that a random *g*, modulo a 1024-bit prime *p*, will imply a subgroup order smaller than 900 bits.

The biggest prime factor of a random integer of *n* bits will have length, on average, about *0.3*n*. It is extremely improbable that the biggest prime factor will be much shorter than that.

**Bottom-line** is that a purely random prime *p* (of at least 1024 bits) and a purely random *g* modulo *p* **will be fine**. To get bad DH parameters, you have to do it *on purpose*.

---

However, some people are arguing for ensuring that *p* and *g* are fine with "stronger" arguments than the probabilistic properties explained above (mathematically, these probabilities are extremely strong, but convincing people is not only about mathematics, but also about psychology). First, *p* will be generated as a ["nothing up my sleeve" number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number) with a completely open and fully described pseudo-random generator. See appendix A of [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) for an illustration (this is for DSA, but it may apply to DH as well). Then there are two ways for *g*:

- The smaller prime *q* could be generated first; then *p* is produced randomly as *p = qr + 1* for random *r* of the right size, until a prime *p* is reached. Then a random *h* modulo *p* is produced, and *g* is set to *g = h<sup>(p-1)/q</sup>* mod *p*. This yields either *g = 1* (with extremely small probability) or a *g* with an order *exactly* equal to *q*, which is fine.
- *p* could be generated as a so-called "safe prime". I.e. random odd integers *u* are generated until both *u* and *p = 2u + 1* are both prime. Then set *g = 2*: the order of *g* is then necessarily equal to *u* or *2u*, and both are fine. Generating a safe prime is computationally expensive, but having *g = 2* yields a slight performance boost when doing the actual Diffie-Hellman.

When the whole process is fully described, as in Appendix A of FIPS 186-4, it can be *verified*, which guarantees against DH parameters which have been made weak on purpose.

Comment: Actually, I would have to disagree that, as long as you pick your DH values randomly, you're probably safe.  If your value $g$ has an order $n$ with a small factor $q$, then the attacker can compute the secret exponents modulo $q$.  If you pick $g$ and $p$ totally at random, there's a nonnegliable probability that $n$ will have a number of small factors; and hence you'll leak a nontrivial part of the secret.  Yes, if you make the secret exponents larger to compensate -- you have to know to do so.