# Diffie-Hellman: Recommendation of the base size?

Tags: public-key, diffie-hellman, key-exchange

Based upon choosing a prime $p$ of recommended [length](https://www.keylength.com/en/4/) and $N=2p+1$, where $N$ is also prime, and $a^2$ is not congruent to $1 \pmod N$, and $a^p ≡ 1 \pmod N$, I believe you can rely upon $a$ as having order equal to $p$.

My question is, what is a good size for $a$? And the reason I ask is because I've heard that you want the base large enough so that most of the power possibilities exceed $N$. What I'm looking for is more formal requirements or an example that provides $p, N, a$ using current recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard approach is to use $N \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ so that $a = 2$ has order $p$ by virtue of being a quadratic residue, *e.g.* in the [RFC 3526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526) groups, chosen by the deterministic procedure described in [RFC 2412](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2412), Appendix E.  Using *any other* groups for finite-field Diffie–Hellman [raises a lot of eyebrows](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67450).

Uniform random exponents of the usual size have negligible probability of being small enough to admit their recovery by real number logarithm computations: even for $a = 2$ and $N \sim 2^{2048}$, the probability of a 256-bit exponent admitting this attack is about $2^{11}/2^{256} = 2^{-245}$ which is a technical word for ‘not gonna happen’.

Of course, you should just use a modern system like X25519 instead of finite-field DH anyway!  Faster, safer, simpler.